# Coredata migration: change value type

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, migration

I've an already shipped application that use Coredata so save all the data. My model defines a value of type BinaryData and I would like to change the type to Integer.

Currently that field is unused, but his type is incorrect. Can I migrate my store without pain? I've tried some approaches but none of them actually worked.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes you can this will helps u : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10833931/core-data-migration-of-attribute-from-string-to-integer-16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way would be to use a mapping model, but I think there is a much more practical solution for you. Because the field was never used, just delete it. The overhead is practically inexistent.

Now all you have to do is lightweight migration:

- Create a new model version.
- Add the Int attribute, delete the old one.
- Change the active model version to the new one.
- Change the options in your call to `addPersistentStore` to include

  - `NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption`
  - `NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption`
- Change your code to use the new attribute
- Eliminate all potential uses of the old attribute from your code

Test it thoroughly before you upload ;-).

Comment: Uhm, now CoreData can't create the ManagedModel. I've also changed the model url adding the 'd':

`withExtension:@"momd"]`

Comment: Seems that this is a different problem. Make sure you do all of the first three steps. Use version management to test the changes.

Comment: That was a silly error, my fault. Renamed the new version and Xcode panicked.

Now there is another issue: if I've NOT installed the old version of the application and install the new one I get a strange error: http://pastie.org/private/rrfprh0fgjgo5xqiymqb7w

Comment: Well, you know the solution. Happy debugging! Revert to what you had before and go through the motions again.